# DataReader is reading only even rows

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was Binding Data from DB in Grid view.But in the datasource 'CountryList' only even rows is added from data reader. whats wrong with this code?

```
using (cmd)
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cn.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                CountryList.Add(ParseDataReader(dr));
            }

            cn.Close();
            return CountryList;

        }
    }
}
```

and the Parse method is:

```
public static  Countries ParseDataReader(SqlDataReader dr)
    {
        Countries MyCountries = new Countries();

        dr.Read();

            if (dr["CountryID"]!=DBNull.Value )
            {
                MyCountries.CountryID = (int)dr["CountryID"];
            }
            if (dr["Code"]!=DBNull.Value)
            {
                MyCountries.Code = dr["Code"].ToString();
            }
            if (dr["Name"]!=DBNull.Value)
            {
                MyCountries.Name = dr["Name"].ToString();
            }
            if (dr["RequiresState"]!= DBNull.Value)
            {
                MyCountries.RequiresState = (bool)dr["RequiresState"];
            }
            if (dr["Order"]!=DBNull.Value)
            {
                MyCountries.Order = (decimal)dr["Order"];
            }

        return MyCountries;
    }
```

FYI: My stored procedure is returning correct number of rows.But datareader reading only the even rows from the result.

Comment: I guess that the problem is in your stored procedure which is retrieving the records.

Comment: It may help if you include method `ParseDataReader` in the question.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I hv checked stored procedure its working fine.

Comment: Then I am afraid that I cannot help you any further. Don't expect me telling that there is a bug in the SqlDataReader class because there isn't.

Comment: I am sure Problem lies in your ParseDataReader code ..

Comment: See, you forward in parse data reader with a second call to dr.Read - thus a row is skipped. Nothing wrong with the data reader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static  Countries ParseDataReader(SqlDataReader dr)
{
    Countries MyCountries = new Countries();
    //dr.Read(); // << remove this
```

You called `dr.Read()` twice.

Answer (score 1):

What code is in the ParseDataReader?  Note you should only call `dr.Read()` once per row, and in the `while()` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks for not showing the relevant code.

Obviously this is wrong. If DR would read every 2nd row - well, many people would realize it.

THere are 2 possible ways this can happen:

- ParseDataaReader makes a dr.read (so a row gets skipped every row)
- The stored procedure does not return the data you think it returns (so you dont even send all the rows you think).

Simple.

Please validate.

---

UPDATE: And, can you read what you posted? There is a dr.READ call in the ParseDataReader method. So, you forwad one, then ParseDataaReader forwards one (row skipped) and parses that.

Comment: @TamalKantiDey Yes, that is likely why you marked the answer as a question that basically took my answer. Great. I make sure not to handle your questions in the future.

Comment: OK.I m new to this coding/development. And thnx 4 ur Attitude.